# Must a proper prayer be fully "voiced" and "articulated" in the "mind's ear?"

Tags: tefilla

*This question applies to silent prayers.*

In order for a prayer to be made properly, must the praying person "voice" or otherwise "articulate" every word of the prayer in his/her "mind's ear?" Or, rather, is it acceptable to pray by "concept," "feeling," "in the heart" or any other non-verbal method?

Comment: http://www.jewsnews.co.il/2013/08/25/halacha-for-today-how-loud-to-pray/. http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1322

Comment: @Danno: Am I correct to interpret these links to mean that silent prayer is **never** allowed except in the case of inability due to health?

Comment: I have no doubt that there are other exceptions, but the general point is that even "silent" prayer is not silent.

Comment: @Danno: I think there might be a miscommunication. I am pointing out that we can "think" in our "mind's ear" (for lack of a better term) by articulating thoughts in the language of our choosing. I am asking if it is acceptable to pray in the a way the does not rise to that level. You are going in the opposite direction (no problem with that, if that's appropriate) by pointing our the requirement for ***Amida***. I am seeking clarification to know if that applies to **all** prayer?

Comment: @Mowzer There is nothing wrong with silent prayer (in fact, it's good in addition to verbal prayer). The question is whether one can fulfill one's formal obligation to pray via silent prayer (the general ruling is that one cannot). Even in the case of someone who is incapacitated and cannot verbalize the prayers, I seem to recall that either the *Mishna B'rura* or R' Moshe Feinstein noted that this is not because we are relying on the rejected opinion that this satisfies the obligation for prayer. Rather, it is more of a symbolic activity so that the prayers are not forgotten altogether.

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, then http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27801 may answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fred said

[Shulchan aruch harav 101.4](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/8/101/4.htm)

> המתפלל בלחש ולא השמיע יצא אבל אם התפלל בלבו ולא הוציא בשפתיו לא יצא שהרהור אינו כדיבור

> the one that prays quietly and did not hear (himself, as he needs to)  fulfilled his obligation,
>   but **if** he prayed in his heart (mind) and did **not** take it out **with his lips he did not fulfill his obligation**, since thought is not "like" speech

[See mogain avrochom 101.2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x467)
(Which the shulchan aruch harav above saw before writing his shulchan aruch)

Where he explaines that **it needs more research (it is questionable)** if praying in the heart counts

And that theoretically it should be enough if he prayed in his heart (mind without using his lips), since prayer is "the service of the heart" and Hashem "know the thoughts of the heart"

But from the gemoro it seems that it does not count

---

So to be sure that it is proper you should say it with your Voice